# Help finding the roots in a trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry, roots, common-root

Rephrasing an old problem, I'm looking forward to finding the roots in $x$ of the following trigonometric function:
$$\sin\left({\frac{\gamma(x\sqrt{C^2-\gamma^2x^2}-(x+B)\sqrt{C^2-\gamma^2(B-x)^2}+2(T-C)B)}{C^2}}\right)-\frac{\gamma(x\sqrt{C^2-\gamma^2(B-x)^2}+(B-x)\sqrt{C^2-\gamma^2x^2}}{C^2}=0$$

Where $B,C,\gamma,T$ are constant parameters. I already know that the function has a real root depending on the values of the parameters but I have no clue how to start solving it. If anyone could help me I would truly appreciate.

Comment: I fixed it, thank you :)

Comment: It's not much but the first thing I see is that: $\left| \frac{\gamma(x\sqrt{C^2-\gamma^2(B-x)^2}+(B-x)\sqrt{C^2-\gamma^2x^2}}{C^2} \right| \leq 1$ Are there restrictions to the constant parameters such that for example they only can be positive?

Comment: I recommend Newton's method. Even $\cos x - x = 0$ doesn't have a nice closed form solution for its root in $(0, \pi/2)$. It is unlikely that your expression does either. Thus numerical methods are your best bet.